# How do I store timestamp or datetime in Orion?

Tags: fiware-orion

I'm using Orion to store context information, and among all the entity attributes there are two that are time specific:

- updated_at
- created_at

How can I store this? Is there a timestamp or datetime attribute type in Orion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use attribute type `date` to store dates, as described in [NGSIv2 specification](http://telefonicaid.github.io/fiware-orion/api/v2/) section "Special attribute types". For example, you could create the following entity:

```
POST /v2/entities

{
  "id": "myEntity",
  "type": "myType",
  "updated_at": {
    "value": "2017-06-17T07:21:24.00Z",
    "type": "date"
  },
  "created_at": {
    "value": "2017-06-17T07:21:24.00Z",
    "type": "date"
  }
}
```

Note that (at least in the newest Orion version, 0.28.0) precision is seconds. In order words, you can create/update with `2017-06-17T07:21:24.238Z` but you will get `2017-06-17T07:21:24.00Z`.

Note also that Orion manages automatically creation and modification dates for entities, i.e. your client doesn't need to manage them. In order to retrieve entity creation and/or modification use them in the `options` URI param, as described in [NGSIv2 specification](http://telefonicaid.github.io/fiware-orion/api/v2/) section "Virtual attributes". For example:

```
GET /v2/entities/myEntity?options=dateCreated,dateModified
```

Comment: Note that in Orion 0.28.0 NGSIv2 is yet an ongoing work, so it has the status of "beta" API. Thus, some minor changes could happen before the final release of the API (e.g. attribute type for dates could be a different keyword than `date` or the way of specifying virtual attributes could change from `options` to other mechanism).

Comment: Thanks!
I'll use more Date fields along with the dateCreated and dateModified ones. So I have two good news: I don't need to care managing dateModified and dateCreated, and I do have a Data type to make temporal queries.